# is to be built another road vs another road is to be built

Tags: grammar

Do I need to invert the sentence if I move "southeast from the roundabout" to the beginning of the sentence?

1. Another road is to be built southeast from the roundabout. ✔
2. Southeast from the roundabout **is to be built another road**.❓
3. Southeast from the roundabout **another road is to be built**.❓

Comment: In declarative sentences the subject (another road), must come before the verb. So, No.2 is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you. But why is this sentence inverted? West of the building is a restaurant. I wrote this sentence but I remember that I learned somewhere that it needs to be inverted.

Comment: Because that's like saying "There is a restaurant", or ""West of the building, there is a restaurant".

Comment: Similarly you could say "South east from the roundabout is another road". This is valid. However, the verb "is" has a different meaning here, it means "exists".  A road which is still to be built, cannot exist yet. - so you can't say " . . . is another road to be built" because that would be illogical.

Comment: This is about grammar, not logic. If we are looking at a plan of road developments, I can say _Southeast of the roundabout is another road yet to be built_. The point is that when _is_ is a full verb meaning _is located_, the inversion the OP asked about is grammatical, but when it is part of a complex verb phrase like _is to be built_ it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a declarative sentence in English, the subject needs to come before the verb. So #1 is correct:

> Another road is to be built southeast from the roundabout.

But #2 is incorrect:

> Southeast from the roundabout is to be built another road (**incorrect**)

#3 sounds awkward. If the road was already in the process of being built, it would be correct to say:

> Southeast from the roundabout, another road is being built.

Otherwise, for the future tense to sound natural, you need a subject and a verb. For example:

> Southeast from the roundabout, they will be building another road.